# How to change size of CharField

Tags: python, django, django-admin, textinput, django-widget

This code is changing sizes of all CharFields in class. How I can change size of one CharField?

```py
formfield_overrides = {
    models.CharField: {'widget': TextInput(attrs={'size': '20'})},
}
```

Comment: Set a specific max_length in your `models.py` file. `field = models.CharField(max_length=264)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a custom model form that overrides the widget for your field:

```
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'my_field': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '20'}),
        }
```

Then use your form in your model admin:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
    ...
```

Note that setting `TextInput(attrs={'size': '20'})` will only affect the way that the form field is displayed in the model admin. If you want to change the length of the column in the database you should set `max_length` instead.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_field = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

Comment: It's cleaner to set the `widgets` attribute for the model form `Meta` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: @IainShelvington I agree that's cleaner. I've updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

For example, there are **`first_name` and `last_name` fields** which are both [CharField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField) in **`Person` model** below:

```py
# "models.py"

from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20) # Here
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20) # Here
```

Then, the 2 sets of code below can only change the size of **`first_name` field** by assigning `PersonForm` to `form` in `PersonAdmin`:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm): # Here
    class Meta:
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'10'}),
        }

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm # Here
```

Or:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django import forms
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person

class PersonForm(forms.ModelForm): # Here
    first_name = forms.CharField(
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'size':'10'})
    )

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = PersonForm # Here
```

Then, only the size of **`first_name` field** is changed on **"Add" and "Change" pages** as shown below:

[image]

[image]

But, assigning `PersonForm` to `form` in `PersonAdmin` doesn't change the size of **`first_name` field** on **"Change List" page**.

So, if making **`first_name` and `last_name` fields** editable as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

# ...

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name') # Here
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name') # Here
    list_display_links = None # Here
    
    form = PersonForm
```

Then, the size of **`first_name` field** is not changed on **"Change List" page** as shown below:

[image]

But, if using [formfield_overrides](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides) as shown below:

```py
# "admin.py"

from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Person
from django.db import models
from django import forms

@admin.register(Person)
class PersonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('first_name', 'last_name')
    list_editable = ('first_name', 'last_name') 
    list_display_links = None # Here
    
    formfield_overrides = { # Here
        models.CharField: {'widget': forms.TextInput(attrs={'size': '10'})},
    }
```

The size of not just **`first_name` field** but also **`last_name` field** is changed on **"Change List" page** as shown below. *I don't know how to change only **`first_name` field** on **"Change List" page**:

[image]